# Why is it the same table even though it is not a prototype

Tags: lua, closures, factory-method

I have this code:

```
function createRect(x, y, w, h)
  local rect = {
    type = "rect",
    x = x,
    y = y,
    w = w,
    h = h,
    translate = function(rect, vector)
      assert(vector.type == "vector2d")
      local rect = shapes.createRect(rect.x + vector.x, rect.y + vector.y, rect.w, rect.h)
    end,
  }

  return rect
end

translate = function(rect, vector)
  assert(vector.type == "vector2d")
  local rect = shapes.createRect(rect.x + vector.x, rect.y + vector.y, rect.w, rect.h)
end

local o = createRect(2,3,4,5)
local q = createRect(2,3,4,5)

print(o.translate, q.translate, translate)
```

Which is some very easy code and is written to test factory functions in Lua and is very reminiscent of the JS module pattern. Something people usually complain about when talking about factory functions is the memory footprint.
Because `o` and `q` are just assigned, of course they have different `translate()` functions, I assumed.
However I was proven wrong:

```
function: 0x7fcdbe600d50        function: 0x7fcdbe600d50        function: 0x7fcdbe600d90
```

Why is this? How can this even be? I assumed to be `o.translate` and `q.translate` to be different functions, however they are the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can this even be? I assumed to be `o.translate` and `q.translate` to be different functions, however they are the same...

Normally you are correct, however Lua 5.2 introduced an optimization where anonymous functions may be cached if certain conditions are met. Specifically, if the values it references doesn't change between construction then the first created instance of that anonymous function gets reused.

Running your example in [repl.it](https://repl.it), Lua 5.1, shows this as one possible output:

```
function: 0xb81f30  function: 0xb81f00  function: 0xb82ca0
```

But running it under [melpon.org/wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/), Lua 5.2+, shows:

```
function: 0x14f0650 function: 0x14f0650 function: 0x14efb40
```

In your example, `createRect` creates and returns a different `rect` table for every call but the field `rect.translate` is being assigned the same anonymous function as the lua value due to this optimization.

Also see

- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-07/threads.html#00339
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-07/msg00862.html
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-05/threads.html#00617